# Find the median in a full min-heap with at most $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor$ comparisons

Tags: data-structures, heaps

I'm thinking to do this recursively using the fact the the left subheap is also a min-heap with its root being the minimum using some variation of Select$\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor$.

Select-Var($H$,$\left \lfloor \frac{len[H]}{2} \right \rfloor$):

1. if $H[1]$ has no children then return it
2. if $H[1]$ has only one child return Select-Var($H[2...len[H]]$,$\left \lfloor \frac{len[H]-1}{2} \right \rfloor$)
3. if $H[1]$ has two children ...?

How can I complete this algorithm? or is there any better way to do this?

Edit:

The second part of the above algorithm is redundant because the heap is assumed to be full - a full binary tree with $n=2^k-1$ nodes.

I also found that the median can be at any level of the tree except for the root.

Comment: There is one child only if the heap has $2$ elements, since the heap is an almost-balanced tree

Comment: The current best upper bound for finding the median is [$2.95 \cdot n$ comparisons](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539795288611?casa_token=q5pjwMev248AAAAA:xR4-3IdBxZ5Iz2csLb5Xpv4nJKzBpaPLLIuX9c8qi8HiT8qy1xu0yZE_SG7MY1tBRA-WdOpHYQ). If you could find the median in min heap using $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ comparisons, then you can improve on this bound to $2.5 \cdot n$ comparisons since building heap takes at most [$2n$ comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap).

Comment: Can it be that if we have $n=2^k-1$ elements this is an easier case?